# Using mixed fonts for one text field when publishing to ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, labeling, map-service

I have the following name field, which appears perfect in ArcMap when i use an Armenian font.

Նոր Նորքի 9-րդ զանգված

The problem is when i publish this as a service the Latin characters appear as Նոր Նորքի □□րդ զանգված when using Armenian or the when using Latin font the armenian text appears □□ □□□□□ 91□□ □□□□□□□

Is there any way of being able to fix this?  I believe i need to use 2 different fonts

Comment: To where are you publishing this as a service?  This would seem to be an ArcGIS for Server or ArcGIS Online problem rather than ArcGIS for Desktop.

Comment: Correct sorry it is an ArcGIS Server problem, published from ArcDesktop for Server.  

I am wondering if there are any label expressions that i can use to apply multiple fonts in ArcGIS Desktop, before publishing.  I could always split the fields but that would be to much work

Answer (score -1):

I had to generate a fonts field and assign the correct font to be used in the attribute table, then have separate label queries for the different fonts

Comment: Could you please expand your answer to include a few steps explaining the process you followed to get to your solution?  You can use the [edit] link below your answer.